# how to avoid java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: neo4j, embedded-database

I have a Java web app and am trying to use Neo4j 2.0. I wrote a servlet that would allow me to observe some of the action in the database. It uses the same singleton database connection that is used by the other servlets in the application, but when I try to access the debug servlet, I get an 'OverlappingFileLockException' error.

Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: Is there anything I have to add to this question to help clarify the problem?

Comment: How about the full stack trace?